# how to convert date which is taken as string and assign some formate in android

Tags: android, date

I have date in below format coming from api response and in pojo i take it as string and now date is taken as string and my concern is Date is deprecated in api 16. 
My main question is how to convert this and assign some date format to it.
"date":1561040449000"

```
historyList.get(position).getTxnDate() = "1561040449000"
   long dateToLong = Long.parseLong(historyList.get(position).getTxnDate());
                                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
                                String dateString = sdf.format(new Date(dateToLong));
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your long typed "date" timestamp to this method and it will return date in specified format:

```
 public static String getDateFromTimeStamp(long date) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        return formatter.format(new Date(date));
    }
```

Comment: i have date in string

Comment: long date = Long.parseLong("date"); will return date in long type.

Comment: i m getting number formate exception

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Thu, Jun 20, 19 07:50 PM"

Comment: add you code to your question and i'll help further.

Comment: added code to question

Comment: I believe it has to do something with parseLong. I am not getting any exception at my end. You can just modify your pojo to accept a long value by default instead of string to avoid this.

Comment: pojo cannot be changed to long